# spotify models.player.load(...) promise not resolving

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

Anyone ever notice the Promise from `models.player.load("context","playing");` simply doesn't come back (which is to say it neither `fail`s nor `done`s)?

This **doesn't happen every time** I try the operation, only sporadically.

Working with API version 1.0.0, on Spotify for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, timeouts don't seem to fail or done.  At least I assume they're timeouts, because of their sporadic appearance, and different behavior for different users.

See later comments on my answer here: [Intermittent issue with tracks snapshot for current user top list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586783/intermittent-issue-with-tracks-snapshot-for-current-user-top-list/20588632#20588632)

Can be pretty frustrating.  Only option I know of at this point is a success flag and a retry timer.